# Where can I find the Android Wear source?

Tags: android, wear-os

Specifically, Marshmallow 6.0.1
I'm looking at this from a manufacturer's Point of View--not trying to edit the source code.
I know that the code is not open source, but I need to port it onto a smartwatch to run Android Wear, and I can't find the release for Marshmallow. I already checked at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+refs. I can't find the "Emerald Release".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: License it from Google, who presumably can then supply you with the source code by one means or another.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is Android-Wear considered open sourced ?

Comment: There are tags for it in the AOSP (e.g., `android-wear-5.0.0_r1`). I have no idea how complete the code is, though. And I'm sure that a bunch of things on a Wear device are proprietary apps and such (e.g., Play Services equivalents).